# Shellcoding problems at Basics

Tags: c, security, shellcode

Hi and Evening to everyone

I am Venturing into Security , but i need to understand few thing, buffer overflows, etc now i want to also know Shellcoding

So i got my CFF explorer ready, got my C Ide (Visual Studio) ready and my brain also Ready

Now i coded something like this in C

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    PSTR lpCmdLine, INT nCmdShow)
{
    MessageBoxA(NULL, "Hi am a C MessageBox","",MB_OK);

    return 0;
}
```

just to show a MessageBox, now compiled and it gave me the executable.

Now what, i used the CFF explorer to get the byte Arrays, and i got so many codes like this

```
unsigned char shell[25741] = {"\xeb\x2a\x5e\x89\x76\x08\xc6\x46\x07\x00\xc7\x46\x0c\x00\x00\x00"
"\x00\xb8\x0b\x00\x00\x00\x89\xf3\x8d\x4e\x08\x8d\x56\x0c\xcd\x80"
"\xb8\x01\x00\x00\x00\xbb\x00\x00\x00\x00\xcd\x80\xe8\xd1\xff\xff"
"\xff\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68\x00\x89\xec\x5d\xc3...."}
```

Now Thats not the main issue here i then try to call it as this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

unsigned char shell[25741] = {"\xeb\x2a\x5e\x89\x76\x08\xc6\x46\x07\x00\xc7\x46\x0c\x00\x00\x00"
"\x00\xb8\x0b\x00\x00\x00\x89\xf3\x8d\x4e\x08\x8d\x56\x0c\xcd\x80"
"\xb8\x01\x00\x00\x00\xbb\x00\x00\x00\x00\xcd\x80\xe8\xd1\xff\xff"
"\xff\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68\x00\x89\xec\x5d\xc3....."}

int WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    PSTR lpCmdLine, INT nCmdShow)
{
    LPVOID shellcode  = VirtualAlloc(NULL, 25741, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE); // allocate memory for shellcode 
    memcpy(shellcode , shell, 25741); // copy bytes of shell to shellcode 

    //execute asm to call shellcode 
    _asm
    {
    mov eax, shellcode
    call eax
    }

    return 0;
}
```

To be Honest, this part i am not sure (Too sure of) and it triggers back an Error from My Visual Studio, I started to make research and i got to find out that even C programs write shellcode as well, but i become Very confused as i dont see why its misbehaving this Way, what could possibly be wrong  How do i call it from my Visual studio? I am very new to this, and i would want it for Educational purpose only.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this seems a basic code execution problem where you want to execute a binary from another C program. If that's the case, this question has nothing to do with IT security and would be more suitable for Stack Overflow.

Comment: The shellcode looks as if designed for Linux, see `\xcd,\x80`. This will not work on Windows.